# onChange not functioning on update form

Tags: jquery, onchange

I have an update form that populates fields based on database values.  The form includes calculations so I set the value for the field to the database values, but added onChange to allow the form to recalculate the numbers if they are updated.  I am certain that it must be a fomatting issue, but I don't know how to resolve it.  Here is an example of what I did:

```
<td><input type="text" Name="price" id="price" size="8" class="TextBox" value="#price_value#" onFocus="this.className='TextBoxSelected';select()" onBlur="this.className='TextBox'" onChange="calculate();" /></td>


    function getFldValue(fldValue) {
      return isNaN(fldValue) ? 0 : parseFloat(fldValue);
    }
    function calculate() {
      var property_SPrice = getFldValue($('#property_SPrice').val());
      var price = getFldValue($('#price').val());
      $('#price').val(property_SPrice + 0);
```

However; when the property_SPrice is changed it just zeros out the price, so I'm not sure what I need to change here in order to get it to work.  By the way I'm new to this, thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Where is #property_SPrice defined, I don't see an element with that id? How does it get updated?

Comment: Here it is:    <td>*Sold Price: $<INPUT TYPE="text" Name="property_SPrice" size="6" value="#property_SPrice_value#" class="TextBox" onfocus="this.className='TextBoxSelected';select()" onblur="this.className='TextBox'"> </td>

Comment: propert_SPrice has to be defined as an ID value not just NAME

Answer (score 1):

this line :return isNaN(fldValue) ? 0 : parseFloat(fldValue);

try this

```
var property_SPrice = getFldValue(Number($('#property_SPrice').val()));
```

or:

```
var property_SPrice = getFldValue(parseInt($('#property_SPrice').val()));

$('#property_SPrice').val() has to be a number/integer not a string version of a number/integer i.e. 9273 not '9273'
```

try `console.log` on  `typeOf $('#property_SPrice').val()` to see what it is

Comment: Thanks, I made the change but unfortunately it did not fix the problem. I think this may be why, this was a form created by someone else and they have this included to get the values from the database:<cfif GetRecord.price NEQ ''><cfset price_value = #GetRecord.price#><cfelse><cfset price_value = ''></cfif>

Comment: what is the value of $('#property_SPrice').val()?

Comment: in other words what is the value from your data base that go's into this field look like(i.e. is a  price $23.99 or a whole number:88 or an integer: 64.256)?

Answer (score 0):

propert_SPrice has to be defined as an ID value not just NAME